# How to pass parameters from xargs to python script?

Tags: python, bash, xargs

I have `command.list` file with command parameters for my python script `my_script.py` which have 3 parameters.

One line of which look like:

`<path1> <path2> -sc 4`

Looks like it not work like this because parameters should be split?

`cat command.list | xargs -I {} python3 my_script.py {}`

How to split string to pararmeters and pass it to python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `cat command.list | xargs -L 1 python3 my_script.py`? This will pass one line (`-L 1`) at a time to your script.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `-I` from `man xargs`

> -I replace-str
>   Replace  occurrences  of  replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, **unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.**  Implies -x and -L 1.

What you want is

```
xargs -L1 python3 my_script.py
```

By the way: `cat` is not necessary. Use one of the following commands

```
< command.list xargs -L1 python3 my_script.py
```

```
xargs -a command.list -L1 python3 my_script.py
```

Comment: Why is `-x` option is needed?

Comment: @mrgloom My bad, it is not needed. `-L` automatically enables `-x`. Even if it didn't you probably wouldn't need it. It's a safeguard to abort and warn in cases in which not all options from the current line can be used in one call due to the `ARG_MAX` limit. For instance in `seq -s' ' 9999999 | xargs -xL1 echo` you get a warning that there are too many arguments in one line to fit into a single call.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what you are trying to do with `xargs -I {} python3 my_script.py {}` there.
But are you looking for,

```
$ cat file
<path1> <path2> -sc 4
....
<path1n> <path2n> -sc 4

$ while read -r path1 path2 unwanted unwanted; do python3 my_script.py "$path2" ; done<file
```

Comment: Yes, it work : `while read -r path1 path2; do python3 show_mouth_landmarks.py $path1 $path2 -sc 4 ; done<item.list`